# How to automount removable usb drives?

Tags: usb, mount, automount

When I plug in a flash drive in my PC (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS), it does not automount. I have to open the Disks Tool and mount the drive manually. The automount setting is enabled:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.media-handling 
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling autorun-never false
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling autorun-x-content-open-folder @as []
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open true
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling autorun-x-content-ignore @as []
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount true
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling autorun-x-content-start-app ['x-content/unix-software']
```

Creating fstab entries is not a good solution for me, because I also want to automount new devices.

Something somewhere must be disabled, but I have no idea where. If anyone has a clue, kindly let me know :-)

Update: As requested in the comments, here's a the log of `journalctl -xe` after attaching a USB device.

```
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2323, bcdDevice= 0.00
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: usb 1-6: Product: Expansion+
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Seagate
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: usb 1-6: SerialNumber: NA8L5XB9
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: scsi host4: uas
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion+       9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC mtp-probe[17138]: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-6"
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC mtp-probe[17138]: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC mtp-probe[17157]: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-6"
Aug 26 16:46:18 PC mtp-probe[17157]: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Aug 26 16:46:22 PC kernel: ....ready
Aug 26 16:46:22 PC kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
Aug 26 16:46:22 PC kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Aug 26 16:46:22 PC kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
Aug 26 16:46:22 PC kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Aug 26 16:46:22 PC kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
Aug 26 16:46:22 PC kernel:  sdc: sdc1
Aug 26 16:46:22 PC kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Also, permissions seem to be correct:

`getfacl /media/<username>`

```
# file: media/<username>
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:<username>:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB covers a lot of what you have here, but do you have the `/media/<username>` directory that is needed for automounting?

Comment: This might help. https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/how-to-automount-file-systems-on-linux Note: I can't comment yet, so I added this to answer C:

Comment: Yes, that exists

Comment: As already stated, creating fstab entries is not a good solution for me

Comment: When you plug in a USB device does `journalctl -xe` output anything about trying to automount the USB?  Your settings in your question look correct, but I am wondering if the `/media/username` folder special permission might be wrong.  One way to check is `getfacl /media/<username>` and make sure you see a line that says `user:<username>:r-x`  As far as `/media/<username>` goes, the owner and group of it should be root for proper mounting.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks for your help. I provided the information you asked for in the question above.